# How to create a helper function in NuxtJs to use inside vuex and components?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to create a plugin for Nuxtjs to log everything I want only in client mode, something like this :

```
// ~/plugins/client-log.js
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
    app.clog = string => console.log(string)
}
```

This  plugin is working in components where I have access to context for example:

```
export default {

  fetch({app}){
       app.clog("some string")
  }
};
```

But I want to be able to use it inside vuex (actions, mutations...). How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're so close, you just need to change one thing:

```
// ~/plugins/client-log.js
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
    inject('clog', string => console.log(string))
}
```

Then you're able to call it like:

```
export default {

  fetch({app}){
       // Note: inject will automatically prefix with a "$"
       app.$clog("some string")
  },

  mounted() {
    // this.$clog can also be accessed within vuex
    this.$clog("I'm in a component")
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I  still can not use it inside vuex actions or mutations, right?

Comment: My apologies, I've updated with how to access within a component/vuex